# why does laravel migration's timestapce('my_col_name') returns Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'my_col_name'

Tags: laravel

In my migration I have two extra timestamp

> $table->timestamp('starts_at');
>
> $table->timestamp('ends_at');

I dont want them to be nullable,problem is,when i run php artisan migrate
I returns

> Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'ends_at'

I have $table->timestamps() at the bottom.
How can I have my custom timestamp column/s and not nullable

**A way around is to simply put nullable() at the end but its not a fix.using laravel 5.7**

Comment: Do you already have records in the table? If so, you either need to make these timestamps nullable, set a default, or empty the table and then migrate.

Comment: i have no data in that table,its a fresh migration

after running php artisan make:migration my_migration_name

Comment: Are you okay with using "dateTime" instead of "timestamp"?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for datetime data type for that field.
Try the below code.

```
$table->datetime('starts_at');
$table->datetime('ends_at');
```

if you want to make this field as nullable try below.

```
$table->dateTime('starts_at')->nullable();
$table->dateTime('ends_at')->nullable();
```

Comment: as i said before, i know a way around with nullable() 
I don't want a hack,I want a solution or answer why it doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

You should try this:

```
 $table->timestamp('starts_at');

 $table->timestamp('ends_at')->default('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

Comment: OP said that using default() is not what he wants so I'm assuming you didn't read the full question.